# Python Selenium Click Button Within A Class

Tags: python, selenium

[image: Login_Via_Email_Button]

In the image above I am trying to click the 'Continue with email' button.  This is the code I have:

```
from selenium import webdriver

Driver = webdriver.Firefox() #Define webdriver to use
Driver.get('https://www.airbnb.co.uk/login')
Element = Driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div[contains(@class,'_p03egf') and (@class, '_18m31f1b')]")
Element.click
```

Either my syntax is wrong or my poor understanding of web pages is letting me down

Any help - much appreciated

Thanks
Rob

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use below solutions, if you want to click on a **Continue with email** button:

**- XPATH**

**Example 1**

```
wait = WebDriverWait(Driver, 30)
     wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//div[contains(text(),'Continue with email')]"))).click()
```

**Example 2**

```
wait = WebDriverWait(Driver, 30)
     wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//div[@class='_bc4egv gs_copied']"))).click()
```

**- CSS Selector**

```
 wait = WebDriverWait(Driver, 30)
     wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, ".\_18m31f1b:nth-child(1) .\_bc4egv"))).click()
```

Dont forget to add below imports

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
```

Comment: Lovely - the 1st example worked a treat (just capital D as I'd capitalised 'Driver' object in my code).  Thanks very much

Comment: Great !! would you kind enough to [accept](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) answer from your end.

Answer (score 1):

I think your XPath is off, from the example you gave, I would assume you want something like this:

```
Element = Driver.find_element_by_xpath("//button[@data-testid='social-auth-button-email']")
```

[w3schools.com](https://www.w3schools.com/xml/xpath_syntax.asp) has a great tutorial on XPath syntax

Comment: Thank you - there seemed to be a timing issue, but once past that your syntax was good

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this code

```py
Element = Driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="site-content"]/div/div/div/div/div/div/div/div[2]/button')
```

Answer (score 0):

```
find_elements_by_class_name('_18m31f1b').click()
```

It should be enough to do what you want as the button seems to be connected to that class and all you want to do is click it.